# Working with Drupal site collaboratively

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm starting to help on the development of a Drupal based site and I got the files for the site on a zipped folder.

I can import the files into Acquia Desktop and it gives me no error and runs the server. However, when I go to the site, it behaves as if it was a **new install** of Drupal, **negating all the work done before**.

Is there a middle step before importing into Acquia that I don't know?

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure how Acquia works, but if Drupal is offering you new install that means that something is wrong with database. It can't connect or database is empty. Check /sites/default/files/settings.php ...is everything ok with database settings.

Comment: Thank you @MilanG , you're right. I was creating a new database when importing. As of this answer, I need to install a module to backup the database. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/51454

Comment: Yes, you can install new Drupal, install backup&migrate and import. But you can also use PhpMyAdmin or some similar tool to export database from old project and import in on new. Or you can use shell, of course. And then just set that settings file to point to new database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to make it official, if Drupal is offering you new install that means that something is wrong with database. Either it's empty or database account information is not correct or something like that.

When you are moving database, you can do it with backup&migrate module (if you want to do all the job from back-end interface).

Or you can use PhpMyAdmin or similar tool to move database to new server. Or you can do it straight from console (shell). In both ways you would have to adjust /sites/all/default/settings.php file with new database user account info.

When moved to new environment check also if all paths needed by drupal to be writable are really writable. Go to Configuration -> Media -> Filapaths and click "Save configuration". If some path is not writable it will get red outline, so you have to make it writable.